# How to POST multipart/form-data in Python with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

Currently working on a project and I need to post this request:

```
curl -X POST "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize" \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-H "x-api-key: xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx" \
-F "file=@<image>.jpg"  #image
```

Tried several times with this code snippet had no luck:

```
import requests
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxxxxxxx',
}
files = {
    'file': ('image.jpg', open('image.jpg', 'rb')),
}
response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize', headers=headers, files=files)
print(response)
```

Am I doing something wrong or missing something?

Comment: seems like the above is correct, edited after the post ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try with this

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
    'x-api-key': 'xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx',
}

files = {
    'file': ('<image>.jpg', open('<image>.jpg', 'rb')),
}

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize', headers=headers, files=files)
```

Comment: It returns <Response [400]>

Comment: Hm, can you update your question with the exact code snippet you try? As you can see there is one more answer with virtually the same code. It's what your curl is doing.

Comment: Edited in my initial question

Answer (score 2):

I made it work with this code:

```
import requests
url = "http://10.0.38.119:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize"
payload = {}
files = [('file', ('<image>.jpg', open('<image>.jpg', 'rb'), 'image/jpeg'))]
headers = {
  'x-api-key': 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxx'
}
response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload, files=files)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: You're not setting the boundary? It's very black boxy how requests set up the multipart requests

Comment: After setting debug logging and looking at the difference between explicitly setting `Content-Type` in the header versus not, I found that when not set by me, requests sets the boundary.
[Setting debug logging](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#http.client.HTTPResponse.debuglevel)


```python
import http.client as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `-H` flag means that you're passing a header, not a file.

```py
>>> import requests
>>> 
>>> headers = {
...     "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
...     "x-api-key": "xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxx"
... }
>>> 
>>> file = {"file": ("<image>.jpg", open("<image>.jpg", "rb"))}
>>> 
>>> r = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/recognition/recognize",
...     headers=headers, files=file
... )
```